# Illegal url address on moss 2007

Tags: mhtml

I try to add the link : 
"mhtml:file://\ipaddress\merging\Human%20resources\file.mht"
to links list on moss 2007 and i've got an error : 
"Illegal url address "

What is wrong ? 
What to do ?

Ish .

Answer (score 0):

The error is right, that is not a valid URL address, in particular the "mhtml:file://" part.

However, a file URL like this should work: `file://\\ipaddress\merging\Human%20resources\file.mht`

(Or, if the target PC is using IIS web services, then `http://ipaddress/merging/Human%20resources/file.mht` might work too.)